# Python deepcopy checker

Tags: python-3.x, deep-copy

I'm studying for final year examination, and it seems that there's a question that asks me to write a function deep_copy_check that checks whether one list is a deepcopy of the other. However, I do not understand what's the use of the conditional statement of the suggested solution provided below, can anyone enlighten me why it is necessary to add `lst1 != lst2`? I feel that `if lst1 is lst2` is sufficient enough.

```
def deep_copy_check(lst1,lst2):
    if lst1 != lst2 or lst1 is lst2:
        return False
    else:
        result = True
        for i in range(len(lst1)):
            if type(lst1[i]) == list:
                result = result and deep_copy_check(lst1[i],lst2[i])
            else:
                result = result and lst1[i] is lst2[i]
        return result
```